# Как работает dict.items()?

Tags: python

Вот сколько работал с dict.items() - никогда вопросов не возникало, потому как всегда предполагал, что он **.items()**  всегда должен возвращать пару: ключ, значение.

```
print({1: 2}.items())  # dict_items([(1, 2)])
```

Почему в цикле можно писать:

```
for k, v in {1: 2}.items()
```

А так нельзя:

```
k, v = {1: 2}.items()
```

Вроде же как по первому коду видно что возвращается кортеж пар: ключ и значение. Почему он тогда не распаковывается? Или я что-то недопонял тут?

Comment: По первому коду видно, что возвращается не кортеж, а список из одного элемента. Точнее даже не список, а специальный объект dict_items, но не суть

Comment: Чтобы можно было выполнить распаковку в два элемента, нужно пустить на распаковку список (или dict_items), содержащий два элемента, например `k, v = {1: 2, 3: 4}.items()`

Comment: И по аналогии в три элемента и так далее `k, v, x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}.items()`

Comment: Вот так можно: `[(k, v)] = {1: 2}.items()`

Comment: @insolor хм, а есть ли какое-то принципиальное отличие от `((k, v),) = {1: 2}.items()` ?

Comment: @andreymal в принципе нет, по идее без разницы во что распаковывать - в список или кортеж. Просто `[(k, v)]` по виду как бы ближе к `dict_items([(1, 2)])`, чем `((k, v),)`

Comment: Интересно, если написать **d = {1: 2}.items()** то распаковать через **k, v = d** не получается, а если так: **d, = {1: 2}.items()**, то распаковка уже работает:  **k, v = d**

Comment: Все эти варианты по сути то же самое — сперва распаковывается в один кортеж, а потом этот один кортеж распаковывается на два элемента k и v

Comment: Потому что `d,` (или то же самое `(d,)`) - это кортеж из одного элемента, в первый (и единственный) его элемент попадает первый (и единственный) кортеж из `items()`. Просто нужно понять, что items возвращает не одну пару ключ-значение, а набор таких пар.

Comment: Получается, что питон чего-то не понимает? И ему надо указывать явно?

Comment: Питон все понимает, просто вы еще до конца не поняли)

Comment: `k, v = {1: 2}.items()` - вот тут вы пытаетесь (условно) список пар распаковать в одну пару, как вы предполагаете, что это должно работать?

Comment: @insolor, сделал эксперимент: **k, = {1: 2}.items()** потом распаковал: **q, qq = k**  И если теперь принтануть, то получится, что **q=1**, а **qq=2**

Comment: Может так будет понятнее: замените во всех примерах `{1: 2}.items()` на `[(1, 2)]`.

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, вы методом тыка пытаетесь понять, а нужно основу понять: `{1: 2}.items()` это примерно то же, что `[(1, 2)]`. `[(1, 2)]` в `k, v` при всем желании не распакуется.

Comment: @insolor, Все, понял. Вообщем, **.items()** возвращает не пару ключ значение, а ИТЕРАБЕЛЬНЫЙ КОРТЕЖ пар: КЛЮЧ, ЗНАЧЕНИЕ. Спасибо!

Comment: `for k, v in {1: 2}.items()` -> `k, v = next(iter({1: 2}.items()))`, то есть сначала нужно взять первый элемент у этой коллекции, а потом уже можно распаковывать. `for` же и перебирает элементы коллекции, которые в случае `.items()` являются кортежами (ключ, значение)

Answer (score 0):

dict.items() возвращает не пару ключ/значение, а список кортежей вида ключ/значение.
Ты пытаешь один элемент (список кортежей), записать в две переменные.

что бы сделать то, что ты хочешь, надо написать что то вроде:

```
k, v = [], []
for key, value in {1:2}.items():
    k.append(key)
    v.append(value)
```